# Vanilla JavaScript version of jQuery .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling

So maybe I'm just not looking in the right places but I can't find a good explanation of how to do the equivalent of jQuery's

```
$('a').click(function(){
    // code here
});
```

in plain old JavaScript?

Basically I want to run a function every time an `a` tag is clicked but I don't have the ability to load jQuery into the page to do it in the way above so I need to know how to do it using plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZNws/

Html

```
<a href="something">CLick Here</a>
<a href="something">CLick Here</a>
<a href="something">CLick Here</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var z = 0; z < anchors.length; z++) {
    var elem = anchors[z];   
    elem.onclick = function() {
        alert("hello");
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: I disagree. IMHO you may destroy the previous bound function. To use "addEventListener" is far better I think.

Answer (score 74):

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() { ... }, false);
```

You have to locate the elements and make a loop to hook up each one.

Answer (score 19):

```
document.getElementById('elementID').onclick = function(){
      //click me function!
}
```

Comment: Ah... should have pointed out I wont know the 'a' tags or ids upfront so need to just say "For ANY a tag clicked....."

Answer (score 19):

Try the following

```
var clickHandler = function() { 
  // Your click handler
};

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var current = anchors[i];
  current.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}
```

**Note**: As Ӫ_._Ӫ pointed out this will not work on IE8 and lower as it doesn't support `addEventListener`.

On IE8 you could use the following to subscribe to `onclick`.  It's not a perfect substitute as it requires everyone to be cooperative but it may be able to help you out

```
var subscribeToOnClick = function(element) {
  if (element.onclick === undefined) {
    element.onclick = clickHandler;
  } else {
    var saved = element.onclick;
    element.onclick = function() {
      saved.apply(this, arguments);
      clickHandler.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var current = anchors[i];
  subscribeToOnClick(current);
}
```

Comment: Don't create functions inside of a loop. It's better to create the function outside of the loop and reference the function inside the loop.

Comment: @PeterOlson mainly I was trying to replicate the style of the original question. I'll update it to be more correct in this sense

Comment: Should probably be noted that IE8 and lower don't support `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ what is the alternative for IE8?

Comment: Well, there isn't an exact alternative. They do have `attachEvent`, but it doesn't accept the 3rd argument to set bubbling/capturing *(bubbling is default)*, and it doesn't set `this` as the element that invoked the handler, but there are workarounds for that using closures.

Comment: ...of course there's the `onclick` property too if you're only assigning a single handler per element/event.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ updated with a basic `onclick` solution for IE8 usage. Not a perfect substitute but should get the job done for most scenarios.

Comment: +1 but `clickhandler();` should be `clickhandler.apply( this, arguments );` just like you did with the `saved` invocation above it.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ you're right. I was being lazy because the my definition of `clickHandler` didn't use them so I didn't bother passing them. But it's much better to do so.

Answer (score 13):

Here you go:

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'a' ), function ( a ) {
    a.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
        // code here
    }, false );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8Lvzc/3/

(doesn't work in IE8)

Also, I recommend event delegation...

Comment: Do you have a reason for not using `[].forEach.call(...)`?

Comment: @pimvdb Well, `call` isn't suitable since a function has to be passed into `forEach`. One would have to use `apply`, so: `[].forEach.apply( ..., [ function () {} ] );`. The `[ function () {} ]` notation is a bit to strange for my taste...

Answer (score 6):

I just stumbled upon this old question.

For new browsers (find support here: https://caniuse.com/?search=querySelectorAll)

My solution would be:

```
function clickFunction(event) {
  // code here
}

for (let elm of document.querySelectorAll("a")) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);
}
```

This is optimized to not create a new function for each element.
This will add an "click" eventListener to each element, so if you do this more than once, several eventListeners for each element will be called.

To replace/set the "click" eventListener use the following code:

```
for (let elm of document.querySelectorAll("a")) {
  elm.onclick = clickFunction;
}
```

Will work on IE9 and up.

Comment: It's easier to read but it's not optimized in any way.  You're still effectively looping through the array of a elements.  [For loops are faster than forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43032526/10633285)

Comment: You are right! I was distracted by some reading I did. The slicker solution is using a for of loop. (edited my solution),

Comment: this is cool, but i noticed it will overwrite any existing onclick handler

Comment: You are right. This will set the onclick event handler instead of adding another one. I updated my solution

Answer (score 3):

This will assign an `onclick` function to every `a` element.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var linkClick = function() {
  //code here
};

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  links[i].onclick = linkClick;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsbin.com/arehed/edit#javascript,html).