# Substitute value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a clever way of substituting / replacing a value in an array

eg.

```
var array = [[1,2,3,'null'],['null',2,3,4],['null','null','null','null'],[1,1,1,1]]
```

the answer should be which i will write to a spreadsheet

```
[[1,2,3,''],['',2,3,4],['','','',''],[1,1,1,1]]
```

The actual array is much bigger than this and spans 1000+ lines

Comment: @Max Makhrov Thanks your answer seems to work best. As quite rightly pointed out google spreadsheet scripts cannot accept =>. I would liked ot have used the elegance of map but cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
var array = [[1,2,3,'null'],['null',2,3,4],['null','null','null','null'],[1,1,1,1]];


var row = [];
var cols = array[0].length;

for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++)
{
  row = array[i];
  for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++)
  {
    if (row[col] === 'null') { row[col] = ''; } 
  }
}

Logger.log(array); // [[1, 2, 3, ], [, 2, 3, 4], [, , , ], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Note: arrows `=>` do not work in Google Sheets, used a simple loop for a [better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach).

Comment: Thanks your answer seems to work best. As quite rightly pointed out google spreadsheet scripts cannot accept =>. I would liked to have used the elegance of map but cannot.
@Peter Leger for whatever reason this method seems to throw out an error when writing the array to spreadsheet, somewhere it has delete an element from an array which says that the array is of incorrect width.

Comment: @mfizz: `@replies` only fire a notification when the mentioned user participate on the post, either as author, editor or commentator, son Peter Leger perhaps doesn't know about your comment.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use `Array.prototype.map`, you could do something like:

```
var arrayWithoutNulls = array.map(line => line.map(el => el === 'null' ? '' : el))
```

Edit as per @charlietfl suggestion: this returns a new array. So bind it to a new variable (as the example above) or immediately return it, but bear in mind the `array` variable will still have the `null` elements.

Comment: Should note this returns a new array and does not modify existing array

Comment: On a couple of comments the OP and an answerer mention "google spreadsheet scripts cannot accept =>". They are actually talking about [tag:google-apps-script]

Comment: Yeah, they have commented about that after I had posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the original array:

```js
var arrs = [
  [1, 2, 3, 'null'],
  ['null', 2, 3, 4],
  ['null', 'null', 'null', 'null'],
  [1, 1, 1, 1]
];

arrs.forEach(function(arr, i) {
  arrs[i] = arr.join(",").replace(/null/g, '').split(",");
})

console.log(arrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `map`. First on the containing array, then on the ones nested inside:

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 'null'],
  ['null', 2, 3, 4],
  ['null', 'null', 'null', 'null'],
  [1, 1, 1, 1]
]

const newArray = array.map(arr => {
  return arr.map(elem => {
    return elem === 'null' ? '' : elem;
  });
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify orig array you could actually use a normal foreach loop and then replace items in array with the splice method

```js
var array = [[1,2,3,'null'],['null',2,3,4],['null','null','null','null'],[1,1,1,1]]


array.forEach(a => a.forEach((b,i) => {
  if (b === 'null') {
    a.splice(i, 1 , '')
  }
}))
console.log(array)
```