# Which is more performant for/forEach if we are accessing current item in loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, for-loop, foreach

Every where people are saying `for` is more performant then `forEach`
e.g.

https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37

[Javascript efficiency: 'for' vs 'forEach'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach)

> But does it holds true when accessing current element in loop.
>
> If not why not if yes what about following code, which gives contradictory results in different cases:

***Logic:***

```
//----------------------------------------
var arr = [], len = 1000000, nos = 100;

for(var t = 0; t<len; t++) {
  arr.push({
    a:'a',b:'b',t:Math.random()
  });
}
//----------------------------------------

//===========forEach start====================
var tp1 =  new Date();
arr.forEach( (ik)=>{
  let tmp = [];
  for(let x = 0;x<nos;x++){
    tmp.push(ik.a);
  }
});
var tp2 =  new Date();
//===========forEach end====================


//===========for loop start(let outside loop)====================
var t1 =  new Date();
let i;
for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  let tmp = [];
  for(let x = 0;x<nos;x++){
    tmp.push(arr[i].a);
  }
}
var t2 =  new Date();
//===========for loop end(let outside loop)====================


//===========for loop start(let inside loop)====================
var ti1 =  new Date();
for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  let tmp = [];
  for(let x = 0;x<nos;x++){
    tmp.push(arr[i].a);
  }
}
var ti2 =  new Date();
//===========for loop start(let inside loop)====================


//----------------------------------------

var dff = t2-t1;
var dffi = ti2-ti1;
var dffp = tp2-tp1;

console.log("Execution Time:- (let outside loop): ",dff);
console.log("Execution Time:- (let inside loop): ",dffi);
console.log("Execution Time:- forEach: ",dffp);

console.log("Execution Time:- forEach - for(inside loop): ",dffp-dffi);
console.log("Execution Time:- forEach - for(outside loop): ",dffp-dff);

//----------------------------------------
```

***Which gives output as follows:***

case 1: nos = 100

```
Execution Time:- (let outside loop):  3739
Execution Time:- (let inside loop):  3699
Execution Time:- forEach:  730
Execution Time:- forEach - for(inside loop):  -2969
Execution Time:- forEach - for(outside loop):  -3009
```

case 2: nos = 10

```
Execution Time:- (let outside loop):  427
Execution Time:- (let inside loop):  396
Execution Time:- forEach:  98
Execution Time:- forEach - for(inside loop):  -298
Execution Time:- forEach - for(outside loop):  -329
```

case 3: nos = 2

```
Execution Time:- (let outside loop):  106
Execution Time:- (let inside loop):  125
Execution Time:- forEach:  90
Execution Time:- forEach - for(inside loop):  -35
Execution Time:- forEach - for(outside loop):  -16
```

case 4: nos = 1

```
Execution Time:- (let outside loop):  62
Execution Time:- (let inside loop):  85
Execution Time:- forEach:  72
Execution Time:- forEach - for(inside loop):  -13
Execution Time:- forEach - for(outside loop):  10
```

case 5: nos = 0

```
Execution Time:- (let outside loop):  17
Execution Time:- (let inside loop):  23
Execution Time:- forEach:  72
Execution Time:- forEach - for(inside loop):  49
Execution Time:- forEach - for(outside loop):  55
```

Comment: If you replace `new Date()` with the more precise `performance.now()`, the `for`-loop gives better results in all cases on V8 / Chrome.

Comment: I running it using node so performance is not defined.

Comment: If you like, on node.js, you can do `node --print-opt-code script.js` to see the resulting optimized machine code and compare.

Comment: Thanks for new insight sir, but even now it is showing same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some analysis I reduced some facts below:

- Basically for loop is more performant then forEach by execution
- Both has a native(c/c++) implementation for looping.
- forEach has native(at c/c++ layer) implementation for accessing current element which is provided in callback.

Deduction

1. In case of third point when we are accessing current element while iteration, `forEach` will give faster result since it will execute at native level but in case of for loop it has to pass to two layers `JS` then `native`
2. There is more efficient variable resolution in case of `forEach` for current_item, index, array as they are passed through callback from native method but incase of `for loop` it is not

Comment: I don't know how exactly the `Array.forEach` method is implementd but i think that the function call of the method is kind of expensive in contrast to the for loop which does not call a function. So there should be a significant difference between the two. I'm not sure if the optimizing compiler of the Javascript runtime can inline a function when the function get's called from native code.