# Array.from vs for loop to traverse an array-like object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

For traversing an array-like object, is better use -- for performance -- `Array.from( ).forEach()` or `for` loop?

Example of an array-like object:

```
let childeNodes = document.querySelector('#someid').childNodes;
```

Iteration with `Array.from().forEach()`:

```
Array.from(childNodes).forEach(node => {
  // do something with node
})
```

Or iteration with `for`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
  // do something with childNodes[i]
}
```

Comment: create a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/) and find out

Comment: for loop should have a bit better performance, but it doesn't mean you should always use for loop. If you wanna break the loop or make the use of index, then yes.

Comment: `Array.from` and a `for` loop are not analogous. `from` is only called once. `forEach` is being called for each item. I would update your question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there are two more interesting variants:

1. The `Array.from` function accepts a second argument which is a callback called for each element. We can expect that to work faster than the `.forEach` method appended to it, as no intermediate array has to be created
2. The ES6 `for..of` loop

But it is a known fact that the old-fashioned `for` loop beats all alternatives. Here is a little snippet that makes the measurements:

```js
const childNodes = document.querySelector('#someid').childNodes;
let i, start, duration, times = 500000;

k = times;
start = performance.now();
while (k>0) {
    Array.from(childNodes).forEach(node => 
        k -= node ? 1 : 0
    );
}
duration = performance.now() - start;
console.log('Array.from with forEach: ', duration.toFixed(2));

k = times;
start = performance.now();
while (k>0) {
    Array.from(childNodes, node => 
        k -= node ? 1 : 0
    );
}
duration = performance.now() - start;
console.log('Array.from callback: ', duration.toFixed(2));

k = times;
start = performance.now();
while (k>0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        k -= childNodes[i] ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
duration = performance.now() - start;
console.log('Oldfashioned for-loop: ', duration.toFixed(2));
    
k = times;
start = performance.now();
while (k>0) {
    for (const node of childNodes) {
        k -= node ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
duration = performance.now() - start;
console.log('for-of loop: ', duration.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<ul id="someid">
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
    <li>test4</li>
    <li>test5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is phrased wrong.

Instead of: `Array.from` vs `for(..)`
It should be: `Array.forEach` vs `for(...)`

And for that question you can find very good answers in SO or a simple google search.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43032526/5739073
- https://thejsguy.com/2016/07/30/javascript-for-loop-vs-array-foreach.html
- https://medium.com/@abustamam/for-loops-vs-foreach-in-javascript-7a977278a39e
- https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37

### tl;dr;

`for` loop is faster.
`forEach` is slower, but better fits [functional programming paradigms](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#iterators--nope).

Comment: Convert an array-like object with Array.from adds some overhead?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/75) a `for` loop is faster than `forEach`, but a `for...in` is slowest.

As mentioned though, the `Array.from` is irrelevant as it's only called once.

Also worth mentioning is that in a real world use case of your example, the slowest operation is likely to be `document.querySelector`. According to this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/11) using `getElementById` is much faster.

A larger takeaway here is to understand use cases and maintainability before worrying about performance; and when you do worry about performance, think about it more holistically.