# multiple array iteration javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, performance-testing

I have a question strictly based in regards to performance while iterating through two different arrays.

My first array is composed in the following way, objects consisting of an {id, number}

```
var arr1 = [{id: 1, number: 7}, {id: 2, number: 5}];
```

My second array is composed of the same id field, and a string value

```
var arr2 = [{id: 2, string: 'foo'}, {id: 1, string: 'bar'}];
```

My question is this, I need to match the id's from the first array with the second array specifically in that order. I wrote my code in the following manner.

```
arr1.forEach(function(x){
   arr2.forEach(function(y){
      if(condition){
         Do something...
      }
   });
});
```

Is there a faster/more effective way to iterate through the arrays without two forEach loops? Or is that configuration the best method for comparing all the values?

The code I wrote works and returns no problem, but I can't help thinking there's a faster (performance wise) method or means of doing the same thing here...

Thanks for any and all insight in regards to this!

Comment: Is `id` going to be unique for each array?

Comment: is the id in an ascending  order? if yes take the id of arr1 and the access to the exact position of the arr2 without loop it

Comment: is `id` sorted in `arr1`?

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach

Comment: This is a *primarily opinion-based* question because you're going to get a lot of **opinions** based of experiences, Etc.  Therefore, this question should be closed.

Comment: what do you want later after finding the same `id`? how many data sets do you have?

Comment: I would have to indicate 'bukharim96' answered this question most accurately by indicating my forEach was less effective than just using the for loop. Thanks for all the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop if you like the syntax better, but `.forEach` is a synchronous function and is the fastest way to completely loop through the arrays. Also, `.forEach` cannot be `break`d so using a `for...of` allows you to stop the iteration after some condition succeeds if you want.

If you're trying to find a specific set of items from within the arrays, you may want to use `.filter`, `.map`, `.find`, `.some`, or `.every`

Answer (score -1):

Well using the native `for..loop` would produce the same results much faster since the `forEach` method is just the same implementation but for arrays. If you prefer speed over *expressiveness* then go for the `for..loop`

Check out this [perf](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/66)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your code runs in **`O(n^2)`** complexity.

What you can do is:

1. sort `arr1` and `arr2` using `mergesort`
2. compare then one by one by same index

In this approach you will get `O(n*logn + n*logn + n)`,  resulting in **`O(n*logn)`**.

Answer (score -1):

Since the id property is supposed to be unique, why not taking advantage of native javascript objects like this :

```
var objects1 =  {
    id_1: {number: 7},
    id_2: {number: 5}
};

var objects2 = {
    id_2: {string: 'foo'},
    id_1: {string: 'bar'}
};

console.log(objects1.id_1.number + ' | ' + objects2.id_1.string);
```

I think this is the fastest way to do that .

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you don't care about this, until you get performance issues

If the performance issue is the your case:

1. Validate performance of different approaches in target browsers using this test suite https://jsperf.com/merging-two-arrays-with-props
2. Use best approach

NOTES

- unedited test suite is executed with 10000 items
- some approaches could be divided into preparation and applying parts, so if you need to merge "static" array several times into others - the performance gain will be great
- performance with open DEV tools usually is smaller (much smaller)

== UPDATE ==

Test results:

- Chrome gives better performance in "convert one array to Object" approach
- Edge  gives better performance in "sort both arrays" approach
- Safari on mac has almost same performance in both "convert one array to Object" and "sort both arrays" approaches (winners in chrome&edge)