# Convert JQuery Each into ES6/7 loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm trying to remove a jQuery dependency and replacing this .each with a loop is proving tricky.

```
// inline <img> when src = .svg so it is styled with CSS 

$('[src$=".svg"]').each(function() { // get .svg 
  var $img = $(this);
  var imgURL = $img.attr("src"); // get src url
  $.get(
    imgURL,
    function(data) { // Get the SVG guts from image file
      var $svg = $(data).find("svg");
      $img.replaceWith($svg);  // Replace img with SVG guts
    }, "xml"
  );
});
```

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried already that isn't working?

Comment: Depending on what you want, you can use either `map()` or `forEach()`. But replacing the `.each()` call isn't the only jQuery dependency. You also need to implement the matching with something else.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ <- everything you need, right there. Come back and ask questions if you have an actual issue

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @AndyFitz, as such, you question is complicated to understand since it is difficult to see what your are asking. Can you please put some more details ? (error message, what blocks you)

Comment: My current code snippet above is the last piece I use that has a dependency on JQuery,  I'm just trying to remove that dependency.
I'm trying this right now: 
`var svgs = $('[src$=".svg"]'); for(var i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++){ }`

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by “proving tricky”?

Comment: https://codepen.io/andyfitz/pen/YObMdE?editors=0110 
- existing working code with testing code commented out

Answer (score 1):

Browsers implement jQuery-style selectors and collection methods. So a jQuery each loop can be be emulated in vanilla JavaScript using `document.querySelectorAll` to return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is an array-like object that's kinda sorta like a jQuery collection:

```
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[src$=".svg"]')
```

You can borrow the `forEach` method from arrays:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, node => {
  // do something
})
```

Most browsers (except IE) actually support the `forEach` method directly on `NodeList`s:

```
nodeList.forEach(node => {
  // do something
})
```

You can also use a for/while loop and access the individual elements using square bracket syntax:

```
for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  // current element is nodeList[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
For loop is the most performant of the above options right ?

Comment: that's a little more [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach)