# index out of range in for loop (duplicate)

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, iteration

I am trying to compare a string value with the value in a slice, in my case slice is **tagsList**. I have to do some functionality on this comparison. Please find my below code.

```
        var taglistlength = len(tagsList)
        var tagFlag bool
        var i int
        var reEmplKey string
        type saveDetails struct {
            BankID           string  `json:"bankID"`    
            LocalGradeDescr  string  `json:"localGradeDescr"`   
            RegularTemporary string  `json:"regularTemporary"`
        }
        var tagsList = make([]saveDetails, 0) 

        reEmplKey = "ID00001"
        tagsList = [{ID00001 Band 9 B PERMANENT}{ID00002 Band 8 C PERMANENT}{ID00003 Band 7 C Temporary}] 

        fmt.Println("taglistlength : ",taglistlength)
        for i = 0; i <= taglistlength; i++{ 
            fmt.Println("tagsList : ",tagsList)
            if (taglistlength == 0){
                tagFlag = true
                fmt.Println("1st condition : ",tagFlag)
            } else if (taglistlength > 0 && tagsList[i].BankID ==reEmplKey){
                tagFlag = false
                fmt.Println("2nd condition : ",tagFlag)
            } else if (taglistlength > 0 && tagsList[i].BankID !=reEmplKey){
                tagFlag = false
                fmt.Println("3rd condition : ",tagFlag)
            }else{
                fmt.Println("error")
            }
        }

        if (tagFlag == true){
         //do some operation
        }
```

on executing this code i am getting the below error:

```
    panic: runtime error: index out of range
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x30 pc=0x8ca606]
```

It is executing properly for the 1st loop and showing error in the 2nd time loop.
Please find my output below:

```
      taglistlength :  0
      tagsList : []
      1st condition :  true

      taglistlength :  1
      tagsList :  [{1000000 Band 9 B PERMANENT }]
      3rd condition :  false
      tagsList :  [{1000000 Band 9 B PERMANENT }]
      panic: runtime error: index out of range
      panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Please help me in solving this issue. I know i am doing some silly logical mistake but i couldn't figure out the issue. It will be very much helpful if i could get the working code.

Comment: Most likely you should only iterate until `i < taglistlength` (not until `i <= taglistlength`).

Comment: Thank you @icza for the response. I will edit my code accordingly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too trivial to be considered a real question. Completion of even a basic introductory material such as https://tour.golang.org would have completely obviated the need to ask it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of errors in this codeblock, so let's start:

- First you need to define your `taglistlength` **again** after this line `tagsList = [{ID00001 Band 9 B PERMANENT}{ID00002 Band 8 C PERMANENT}{ID00003 Band 7 C Temporary}]`. I believe that line is in the wrong place because you even define `tagList` after that line, if so , please edit your question.
- As @icza stated in the comment you have to do `i<taglistLength`, not `<=`. In Go, arrays are 0-indexed , so the index equals to the array length is out of bounds.
- If you want to be on the safe side you can do this `for _,tag:= range tagsList{
  ...}` . This is a `foreach` block. Now you can use `tag` instead of `tagList[i]`.Many people are against using it , but it is still an option. It also prevents out of bound errors.
- You don't need to check `tagListLength>0` in every `else if` block. First one is enough for your logic. *This is just a suggestion.*

So in the end, either use `foreach` version of golang, or fix your condition to `i<taglistLength`, and make sure that you are initalizing `taglistLength` at the correct line.

Comment: Thank you @atayenel. I will do the changes u have suggested and run my code.

Comment: `Many people are against using it` - who are these people and why are they against using `range`?

Comment: @Gavin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach This question argues that `for` is more efficient in JS. I don't want to put this topic on the center of question though.

Comment: @atayenel That questions is comparing `for` and `forEach` in JavaScript. You are talking about `for` and `for range` in Go. I don't see the similarities.

Comment: Thank you @atayenel. it worked for me.