# Is there a performance difference between for...in and .forEach()?

Tags: javascript

I was curious if anybody knows if one is faster than the other in either specific use cases or in general, and why.

Specifically, I'm referring to

```
for (let myVariable in myArray) { *do something* }
```

and

```
myArray.forEach(myVariable => { *do something* })
```

Comment: `for..in` should be used for iterating the keys of an object, while `forEach` would be more equivalent to a regular `for` loop. `for...of` is basically the same as `forEach` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in - note specifically where it says `for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.`

Comment: Also, relevant - [don't use `for...in` with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript efficiency: 'for' vs 'forEach'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach)

Comment: 1) It's not a duplicate question. for...in is not the same as a for loop. 2) Vlaz, yes, it's optimization. Thank you for your invaluable insights. 3) tymeJV thanks for actually helping to answer the question instead of making snarky comments or incorrectly labeling this as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I found an article to back up my opinion that for loops must be faster since they don't have a callback to deal with Wich also is my answer.

https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray.forEach(myVariable => { *do something* })
```

If you use this it'll optimize your code and speed. As forEach loop won't create external indexing like for loop. More of above it will allow you to access it's different elements easily. For further use cases, you may visit `www.javascriptinfo.com`

Comment: Chiragkumar, to the best of my knowledge a regular for loop is faster than .forEach(), and for...of is even faster than that. I'm not sure .forEach() optimizes for speed

Comment: Hi, yoursweater, Kindly analyse below information.
foreach vs. for: 
Performance
When accessing collections, a foreach is significantly faster than the basic for loop’s array access. When accessing arrays, however–at least with primitive and wrapper-arrays–access via indexes is dramatically faster.
Timing the difference between iterator and index access for primitive int-arrays
Indexes are 23-40 percent faster than iterators when accessing int or Integer arrays.