# Convert a json array of objects into a different format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How do I convert the following sample response data to the desired JSON format listed below? Thank you.

## My logic

```
arr = arr.map((e) => { e.title = JSON.parse(e.title.replace(/'/g, '"')).title; return e; })
```

## My current response data

```
arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
     "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"]
```

## Desired JSON format

```
arr = [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: "{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'YAHSHUA', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Exam2', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code,

Because if you are using forEach or something it will affect your code performance.

I will recommend this way if you want to handle large data's. If you have less data then use other answers above to achieve your output with less code.

For your reference [Javascript efficiency: 'for' vs 'forEach'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach).

```
var arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
  "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"
];

var result = [];

for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  result.push({id: i, title:arr[i]}); 
}

console.log(result);
```

For loop analysis report : https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS

Answer (score 6):

Um, just

```
 arr.map((title, id) => ({ title, id }))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` to return the desired output:

```js
const arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
     "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"];
     
const result = arr.map((item, index) => ({
  id: index,
  title: item
}));

console.log(result);
```

In this way, you return an array of objects that have a `title` property of type `string`. If you want to output the `title` value as an object, you can parse the value with `JSON.parse()`:

```
const result = arr.map((item, index) => ({
  id: index,
  title: JSON.parse(item)
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not difficult, you have to map the array as you were doing, and return the new object:

```js
arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
     "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"]

mapped = arr.map((elem, index) => {
  return ({
    id: index,
    title: elem    
  });
});

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using forEach loop create an object with required properties and replace the original object in the array

```js
var arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
  "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"
]
arr.forEach((e, i) => {
  arr[i] = {id:i,title:e};
})
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` where the index is the `id`:

```js
const arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}", "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"],

res = arr.map((title, id) => ({id, title}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

use currElement, index as the parameter of map then return the new object of `{"id":index,"title":currElement}`

```js
let arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
     "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"];
     
let newArr =arr.map((currElement, index) => {
  return {"id":index,"title":currElement};
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
 "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"]

 for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++){
  arr[k] = {'id':k, 'title': arr[k] };
 }
 console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var arr = ["{'department': 'YOWI', 'timelimit': '01:05:02', 'sub_title': 'PRE-EMPLOYMENT ASSESSMENT  TEST PART 8', 'id': 185, 'random_code': '50-76997961114', 'title': 'Hey', 'instruction': '?', 'created_at': '2019-03-06'}",
        "{'department': 'Department Exam 2', 'timelimit': '01:05:08', 'sub_title': 'Just a test exam 2', 'id': 142, 'random_code': '50-3910111611011', 'title': 'Assessment', 'instruction': 'Hey Jude', 'created_at': '2019-02-27'}"];

    var new_arr = [];

    for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        new_arr[i] = {'id':i, 'title':arr[i]}
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(new_arr));
```