# if statement wrong syntax

Tags: javascript, function

I was doing some javascript exercises and although I did manage to make this one correctly, I'm pretty confused.

So this is an exercise where the average of a list of marks has to be compared with a given value range to return a string that responds whether the mark was sufficient or not. I found that when compare using a > operator, it returns undefined. Even if the upper limit is also given and that alone (without the lower border value + > operator) does return the string. I don't really understand why this is.

Thanks for your help

```
const marks = [ 80, 80, 50 ]

console.log (calculateGrade (marks));

function calculateGrade(marks) {
    let markstotal=0;

    for (let mark of marks)
        markstotal += mark;
        let average = markstotal / marks.length;

         if (average <= 59)
        return "F";
         if (average < 59)
         return "mehh";
         if (average > 70 && average < 90)
         return "oh yeah mate";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const marks = [80,80,50]
function calculateGrade(marks){
    var markstotal = 0
    marks.forEach(mark => markstotal+=mark);

    console.log(markstotal)
    let average = markstotal/marks.length
    if (average <= 59)
        return "F"
    else if (average > 59 && average <70)
        return "meh"
    else
        return "Fuckyeahhmate";
}
console.log(calculateGrade(marks))
```

I suggest using .forEach method instead.
if you want to iter through a loop is also possible

```
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(myStringArray[i]);
    //Do something
}
```

Please paste the code next time!!

Comment: Why is the forEach method preferable? Is it quicker?

Comment: It's actually not quicker. Using it actually improves readability. More towards functional programming whereby at a glance we can tell what the code is doing. In my opinion, since calculating the average can be done in a simple one-liner why not. The link below
explains it well. but its really down to personal preference.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach

Answer (score 0):

You don't return something for all possible values of `average`. In your example the value of `average` will be 70, which does not meet any of the available `if` conditions in your code and so it reaches the end of the function without returning anything. The default return value is `undefined`.

Make sure your function always returns something. Lets try this instead.

```
const marks = [80, 80, 50]

console.log(calculateGrade(marks));

function calculateGrade(marks) {
    let markstotal = 0;

    for (let mark of marks)
        markstotal += mark;
    let average = markstotal / marks.length;

    if (average < 60)
        return "F";
    else if (average < 70)
        return "getting hot";
    else if (average < 90)
        return "oh yeah mate";
    else 
        return "you are a god!";
}
```

Comment: @Justalamp if any of the answers solve your problem you can upvote, and accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left :)