# How to push an array into another

Tags: javascript

A very basic question but still learning.

I have a 1D array say = `[a,b,c]`.

and another 2D array = `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.

How do I push the array into beginning of each row of 2D array so that my array result looks like this.

`[[a,1,2,3],[b,4,5,6],[c,7,8,9]]`.

Comment: what does not work? have you tried anything?

Comment: Will your 2d always have the same amount of elements in it as your 1d?

Comment: Yes abraham the element will always be same.

Comment: see my solution unshift will work to add element to start of array. @Mask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate each item from 2D array and add 1D array value into it.

For more help please check [Unshift](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp#:~:text=The%20unshift()%20method%20adds,use%20the%20push()%20method.)

```js
var test = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var tests = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

var index = 0;
tests.map(item => { //Iterate each item from 2D araay
  if (index < test.length) { // Check if we have any item in 1D array to avoid crash
item.unshift(test[index++]); // Unshift each item so you can add value at 0 index.
  }
});

console.log(tests);
```

Comment: i got this output is faster compare to other one. i tested all answer including my.

Comment: voted. but dont understand the logic if `//` comments were provided in the answer I could have understand it faster.

Comment: @Mask, I have added comments.

Answer (score 2):

```js
array1 = ["a","b","c"];
array2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];


for(var i = 0; i< array2.length;i++){
  array2[i].unshift(array1[i]);
}

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: just a small question is this the fastest solution as my data can grow big?

Comment: i need to know what will big data. but this will not be fastest. but using exisitng array method to do array operation always recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over one of the array and use `unshift` to push value at `0` index.

```js
var x = ['a','b','c'];
var y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

y.forEach((item, index) => item.unshift(x[index]));
console.log(y);
```

Comment: this will short line of code. Upvoting this because this used same logic which i gave only different way to do. THanks

Comment: is foreach faster then for loop?

Comment: @aviboy2006 We probably are writing code at same time. But you were bit faster than me.

Comment: i will be faster but you wrote less lines of code.

Comment: @Mask have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution with `.map()` and the rest operator

```js
let singleArr = ["a","b","c"];

let multiArr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

let result = multiArr.map((el, i) => [singleArr[i],...el])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is also one of another way to do same logic. Upvoting on this.

Comment: I just want to tick the answer where the loop is fastest. Now I have for,foreach and map. I realize bt the document provided that for is faster than for each.