# How to select an element with attribute "role"?

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom, alert

I already learn how to alert element by tag.

```
 alert(document.querySelector("html")
.innerHTML);
```

I want to use alert by role. I dont know how to start this so I ask here for any idea.
By the way.
role="article"

Answer (score 3):

That would be [attribute selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
const firstArticle = document.querySelector("[role=article]");
const allArticles  = document.querySelectorAll("[role=article]");
```

You can loop  - here I convert to array using the ...spread operator because some of the earlier newer browsers do not have forEach on HTML collections

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("[role=article]")]
  .forEach(article => console.log(article.innerHTML));
```

Newest Chrome, Firefox and Edge can do

```
document.querySelectorAll("[role=article]")
  .forEach(article => console.log(article.innerHTML));
```

Note: forEach is [somewhat slower than for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach), but is more readable. If you do not have thousands of articles on the page it will not matter. If you DO want to use for, then

Comment: Isn't ```forEach``` slower than ```for``` loop?

Comment: Yes. But do you think it matters with 10 articles on a page?

Comment: And then we need to look at for..in: `for (let value of myArray) {
  console.log(value);
}` is THAT slower than `for (let i=0, n=myArray.length; i<n; i++) {
  console.log(myArray[i]);
}`

Comment: Thank you sir then how to add alert?

Comment: The console.log shows the content if you press F12. If you replace console.log with alert in the loop, you will get an alert for each article - but that would be very annoying, so perhaps don't alert?