# Can't remove list of appended children on click (li elements) - Stopwatch app- Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have a small project, a stopwatch and what I want to do is:

**When you click on "Reset Laps", the list of saved laps disappear**

***What I tried***

1.

```
function removingLaps() {
  laps.style.display = 'none'
}
```

and of course it works, but I have another function in the code that you will see from the snippet that limits the number of laps that can be saved to 5. if I just say `display: none`, the `li` elements are still existing in the DOM so the function doesn't work.

2.

```
function removingLaps() {
  laps.remove()
}
```

but in this case unless you refresh the page, the `ul` will be gone, so there would be no place to append the `li`s.

3.

```
function removingLaps() {
  let lapsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.lapsss')
  lapsToRemove.remove()
}
```

but it says that is not a function. If I try with `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`, it works, but it cancel the laps one by one. One click - one lap deleted.

I also tried to get the `li`s by tag name, but it says that cannot set `remove()` of null.

I really don't know what else to try.

**The Snippet**

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container')

let start = document.querySelector('.start')
let pause = document.querySelector('.pause')
let reset = document.querySelector('.reset')
let laps = document.querySelector('.laps')
let lapCrono = document.querySelector('.lapcrono')
let resetLaps = document.querySelector('.resetlaps')

let timer

let m = 0
let s = 0
let ms = 0

//START button **************
function runCrono(){
  container.innerText = (m<10?'0'+m:m) + ':' + (s<10?'0'+s:s) + ':' + (ms<10?'0'+ms:ms)
  ms++

  if(ms == 100) {
    ms = 0
    s++
  }

  if(s == 60) {
    s = 0
    m++
  }
}

start.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  if(!timer) {
    timer = setInterval(runCrono, 10)
  }
  

})



//Lap button *************+
function lap() {
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  if(timer) {
    li.innerText = (m<10?'0'+m:m) + ' : ' + (s<10?'0'+s:s) + ' : ' + (ms<10?'0'+ms:ms)
    laps.appendChild(li)
    li.setAttribute('class', 'lapsss')
  }
  
  if(document.getElementsByTagName('li').length >= 5){
    lapCrono.disabled = true
  }
}

lapCrono.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  lap()
  })


//PAUSE button ***************
pause.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  clearInterval(timer)
  timer = false
})



//Reset Button ****************
reset.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  container.innerText = '00:00:00'

  clearInterval(timer)
  timer = false
})

//Reset Laps*******************
resetLaps.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  removingLaps()
  lapCrono.disabled = false
})

  
function removingLaps() {
  let lapsToRemove = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
  lapsToRemove.remove()
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: 0;
}

body, html {
  background: url(speed.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  font-family: verdana; 
}

.outcontainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="outcontainer">
    <div class="container">00:00:00</div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="start">Start</button>
      <button class="lapcrono">Lap</button>
      <button class="pause">Pause</button>
      <button class="reset">Reset</button>
      <button class="resetlaps">Reset Laps</button>
    </div>

    <ul class="laps">
      
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('li')` returns a collection, not a single element, so `lapsToRemove.remove()` will not work. Check the browser console, you will see the error in the console.

Comment: I know it doesn't work, but that was just another thing I tried

Comment: Another problem is that you do not call `removingLaps` function when the reset button is clicked. Here's a working [Demo](https://jsbin.com/gihipulada/1/edit?js,output).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: The duplicate posted above shows how to work with the output of `querySelectorAll`; that is, loop over the results.

Comment: @Yousaf YES!!!! How I didn't think of empty innerHTML. jeez, thanks a lot!! "Reset" button is only for the timer anways...

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you very much! I'm reading it

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the following code:

```js
function removingLaps() {
  let lapsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.lapsss')
  lapsToRemove.remove()
}
```

The problem is that `document.querySelectorAll` will return an array of HTML elements, not all of them at once. A solution would be something like the following:

```js
function removingLaps() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.lapsss').forEach(e => e.remove())
}
```

This works by selecting the array of laps, and for each element it calls the function with the element passed as the argument. It is functionally equivalent to this for loop:

```js
function removingLaps() {
  let lapsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.lapsss')
  for (let i = 0; i < lapsToRemove.length; i++) {
      lapsToRemove[i].remove()
  }
}
```

Comment: "for loops are generally slower than most native functions"... citation needed. If I were you, I'd leave blanket statements like that out of answers without proof to back them up...

Comment: [Javascript efficiency: 'for' vs 'forEach'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43032526)

Comment: @Yousaf interesting, I will add that in.

Comment: I think you don't need to mention about the performance difference between `for` loop and `forEach`.

Comment: @Yousaf ok, I'll remove it

Answer (score 1):

I used the code from your previous post!!!
I think I did what you asked.

1. **Lap** - When the laps become 5 - the sixth is recorded in place of the first and so the records are scrolled indefinitely.
2. **Reset Laps** - is Done

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container')

let start = document.querySelector('.start')
let pause = document.querySelector('.pause')
let reset = document.querySelector('.reset')
let laps = document.querySelector('.laps')
let lapCrono = document.querySelector('.lapcrono')
let resetLaps = document.querySelector('.resetlaps')

let timer

let m = 0
let s = 0
let ms = 0

//START button **************
function runCrono() {
    container.innerText = (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ':' + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s) + ':' + (ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms)
    ms++

    if (ms == 100) {
        ms = 0
        s++
    }

    if (s == 60) {
        s = 0
        m++
    }
}

start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!timer) {
        timer = setInterval(runCrono, 10)
    }
})



//Lap button *************
var limitLaps = 0;
function lap() {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('laps')[0];
    var y = x.children;

    if (limitLaps < 5) {
        limitLaps++;
    } else {
        limitLaps = 0;
    }

    if (y.length < 5) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        if (timer) {
            li.innerText = (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ' : ' + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s) + ' : ' + (ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms)
            laps.appendChild(li);
        }
    } else {
        var li = y[limitLaps];
        if (li === undefined) { limitLaps = 0; var li = y[0]; }
        if (timer) {
            li.innerText = (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ' : ' + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s) + ' : ' + (ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms)
        }
    }
}

lapCrono.addEventListener('click', () => {
    lap()
})

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('li').length)

//PAUSE button ***************
pause.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = false
    start.innerText = 'Start'

})



//Reset Button ****************
reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.innerText = '00:00:00'

    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = false
})

//Reset Laps*******************
resetLaps.addEventListener('click', () => {
    laps.innerHTML = '';
})

if (laps.length >= 5) {
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = false
}
```

```css
body,
html {
    background: url(speed.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    font-family: verdana;
}

.outcontainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 90vw;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20vh;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="outcontainer">
    <div class="container">00:00:00</div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="start">Start</button>
        <button class="lapcrono">Lap</button>
        <button class="pause">Pause</button>
        <button class="reset">Reset</button>
        <button class="resetlaps">Reset Laps</button>
    </div>

    <ul class="laps">

    </ul>
</div>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: When you get enough ratings to be able to vote, I will be happy to give me a positive rating on this post! Good luck with the project, @Mailer ! :)