# Continue inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, loops

It is standard practice to `continue` inside a loop if a certain condition is met/unmet. In a Javascript `forEach` loop, this produces a syntax error:

```
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
values.forEach((value) => {
    if (value === 3) { continue; }
    console.log(value);
})
```

```
SyntaxError[ ... ]: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement
```

This happens whether I use `function` or an arrow function. How can you `continue` inside a `forEach` loop?

Obviously, you could do an inverse case (`if (value !== 3) { ... }`), but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Use `return` rather than `continue`.

Comment: `forEach()` isn't a loop, it's a function. If you want a loop, use `for (const value of values) { … }`

Comment: @Ouroborus `return` rather than `continue` does work correctly (+1) - it's behavior is not immediately obvious, however. It's easy to think that you are returning the parent function instead of the arrow function within the `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @robertklep stated forEach() is not a loop, it is a function. You cannot use the `continue` keyword inside a forEach loop because its functionality is meant to loop each item in the array.

To achieve the similar behavior you can use,

```
  for(let item of values){
     if (item === 3) { 
      continue;
     }
     console.log(item);
  }
```

Comment: So is there any benefit to using `forEach` versus a `for ... of ... ` loop?

Comment: @ChrisCollett depends on your requirement. for more information read the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach

Answer (score 2):

For practical purposes, return in a forEach() callback is equivalent to continue in a conventional for loop but it isn't the most idiomatic use of functional programming patterns

To solve that, you can filter before you loop:

```
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
values.filter(v => v !== 3).forEach((value) => {
    console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: Although this does not answer the original question, this does feel like the more correct solution. Since forEach is more of a functional pattern, be consistent and also filter before.

Answer (score 1):

in forEach method you can use `return`, it will work like `continue` in a loop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_continue