# the object hasn't be modified after applying forEach in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Below is the demo function to show how I encountered a problem when using `forEach` to combine the data into the object.

```js
async function fetcher(){
    var testObject = {}

    [1,2,3].forEach(async (num) => {
    testObject[num] = await db.collection.find(name: num)
})
    console.log(testObject)
}

fetcher()
```

Empty object `{}` is logged, may I ask why?

Comment: Because you didn't wait for the loop to finish. Use `await Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(...` or a normal loop `for (const num of [1, 2, 3]) {...`

Comment: May I ask is using a normal loop slower? @Konrad

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031988/javascript-efficiency-for-vs-foreach